# Is it always safe to call getClass() within the subclass constructor?

Tags: java, class, constructor, classloader, jls

[An article on classloading](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html) states that the method [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) should not be called within a constructor because:

> object initialization will be complete only at the exit of the
>   constructor code.

The example they gave was:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
    public MyClassLoader(){
        super(getClass().getClassLoader()); // should not call getClass() because object
                                            //    initialization will be complete only at
                                            //    the exit of the constructor code.
    }
}
```

However from what I know, the native final method `getClass()` will always return the [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object of that object instance, regardless of *where* it's called (within the constructor or not).

Will calling `getClass()` within the constructor **ever** give us problems?

If so, what are some examples whereby calling `getClass()` within the constructor would give us errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Will calling getClass() within the constructor ever give us problems?
>     If so, what are some examples whereby calling getClass() within the constructor would
>     give us errors?

Using `getClass()` in constructor in this manner will *always* result in a compilation error, since `this` cannot be referenced before `super()` has been called.

```
Main.java:17: error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
        super(getClass().getClassLoader()); // should not call getClass() because object
              ^
1 error
```

You can test it yourself on http://ideone.com/B0nYZ1.

The `Class` is ready, but the *instance* can't be used to reference the `Class` yet.

Still, you *can* use the `Class` reference in constructor, but you have to do it in a slightly different way: `super(MyClassLoader.class.getClassLoader())`

Also, you are free to use `getClass()` in your constructor *after* the supertype constructor has been called - as you already pointed out, the object is basically ready after that and the `Class` reference can be inferred from the instance.

Comment: On Eclipse, even though it says "error", it compiles and runs just fine. I took the compiled `.class` file and manually run it with `java` command. **It runs**.

Comment: @Pacerier a) Eclipse is not a compiler, it's an IDE; please provide the exact version of `javac`/JDK and verify the compilation process by calling `javac` on the source manually, b) it doesn't compile, neither on Ideone nor on my box, JDK 8u5, c) Please post the exact `.java` source and compiled `.class` file online to allow disassembly. BTW I hope you hadn't copy-pasted the code I had on Ideone - I've edited it twice in the meantime, one of the version did actually compile *because it used `MyClassLoader.class` instead of `getClass()`*...

Comment: I'm using Eclipse's compiler ECJ and it compiles to a .class file which you can view at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53jM4a9X2fqZHBOcldxV1Vnb2s/edit?usp=sharing . The .java source is already in the question.

Comment: @Pacerier disassembly of your code by JAD shows: `// Decompiled by Jad v1.5.8g. Copyright 2001 Pavel Kouznetsov.
// Jad home page: http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) 
// Source File Name:   MyClassLoader.java


public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{

    public MyClassLoader()
    {
        throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tCannot refer to an instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor\n");
    }
}` - also, the error message is visible in plain text in the .class file;

Comment: tl;dr - it *doesn't* compile by itself, *doesn't* run fine, if you'd actually run it you'd got a stack dump. **It doesn't run**, period.

Comment: Ok I've realised the mistake: was running with a version of `TestMain` that loaded `MyClassLoader` but skipped instantiation, hence giving the "false positive". Thanks for your time and help in debugging.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. A disassembler is always a handy tool to have, by the way; if something strange happens, bytecode analysis & disassembly works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you shouldn't call parent class methods, at least in a super() invocation, is that since the parent object has yet to be built, there is no way of knowing if the method will run correctly. You have to remember that the call happens before the parent constructors get a chance to prepare it's data.

After a super() invocation you should be fairly safe to use parent methods, within reason, because the parent objects have all finished what they need to be considered ready to use. I saw within reason because parent methods may call overriden child methods that you must ensure are safe to call during construction.

Unsafe:

```
public static class Base {
    public final void print() {
        System.out.println( this.get() );
    }

    public int get() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public static final class Sub extends Base {

    private int x;

    public Sub() {
        super();
        this.print();

        this.x = 1;
    }

    public int get() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

Safe:

```
public static class Base {
    public final void print() {
        System.out.println( this.get() );
    }

    public int get() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public static final class Sub extends Base {

    private int x;

    public Sub() {
        super();
        this.x = 1;

        this.print();
    }

    public int get() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

Edit - Edit:
After retrying the following code and calling getClass(), it does not actually compile. So completely ignore the previous statements about Object.getClass() being the only available method to call before parent initialization. I have no idea how that got missed, and I am sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Yes it's called before the parent's constructors, However the method **will** run correctly, because it doesn't rely on the state of the object instance (and the `Class` object is already fully built by the time we enter its constructor). That's the *exact* reason why it's the only method we can call before a call to the super constructors....

Comment: Is your conclusion saying that the article is **wrong** because calling `getClass()` within the constructor will never give us errors?

Comment: -1 - Although I agree with the first paragraph of this answer, I strictly prefer science to handwaving. Not directly addressing the main issue (`Will getClass() (...) ever give us problems? (...) what are some examples [that] would give us errors?`), paraphrasing the content of the question as the answer, using phrases like `you should be fairly safe (...) within reason`, `probably safe, although I wouldn't count on it`, not to mention that last `Edit:` - and all that with no references, no concrete examples nor evidence of whatever.

Comment: @Pacerier Ignore my previous comments. I was under the assumption it was compiling on my machine when it wasn't. It's what I get for attempting to work this late. I have deleted my previous comments to avoid further confusion and signing off before I accidentally do this again on another answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ javac whose/MyClassLoader.java
whose/MyClassLoader.java:5: error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
        super(getClass().getClassLoader());
              ^
1 error
```

I know it's late in the day.

Comment: For some reason I *can* compile and run it fine on Eclipse. *Weird*, any idea why is that so?

Comment: Luna says: Cannot refer to an instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor MyClassLoader.java

Comment: @vaxquis, You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561873/is-it-always-safe-to-call-getclass-within-the-constructor#comment-39919953